# Possible to have generic constraints in Arrays?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to have TypeScript constrain the 2nd index using the first argument?

For example:

```
type Data = {
  FOO: number
  BAR: string
}

type DataKeys = keyof Data

type SpecialArray<T extends DataKeys = DataKeys> = [T, Data[T]]

// I want both of these array to fail because the 2nd argument's type
// is determined by the first argument
const arr1: SpecialArray = ['FOO', 'wrong'] // 2nd argument should be `number`
const arr2: SpecialArray = ['BAR', 666] // 2nd argument should be `string`

// This works well with functions
const specialFunction = <T extends DataKeys = DataKeys>(key: T, value: Data[T]) => {
  return
}
specialFunction('FOO', 'wrong')
specialFunction('BAR', 666)
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKUBiB5PALigDsBXAWwCMIAnLKAIQEEAlYgZ2FoEsSBzDAF8MGUJFgI4AaQggOKKAGs5AewBmkxKPHQAypADGPOABtmtWnBAAeACpQIAD2AQSAEwXxEs%20Yu8ychwAfIoA2nYANFpwEQC6caIA9ElQAJJQAO5wJMBQVKrAABZQGlDFEBzQcJbW5apQ6nA8pvkQhnBkVeVF0ABMHlA1-JRuwADkCroYKVA8Cu4QrrQUfBDu%20SA90Oo8tFxDtCMUYxiGqiQHNbQAjMQG7SbmtVuoYeP4eOPR45m0F-xxnEoLMBhthqNclAOEVVGRTBsaFAAAbkah0ZFnC5XSx9e5GJ4WKyvKDvFisb5QABsNOBoMGEJOUJhcIRbRRXF4AkxM1SdiK8yyqloSgUmQgplamR4xUaZBIhmAPGxWMueQ4BLMOHliuVJEU9kcLjcnhivgUqAC5uCAAoVCBiFEoAA3MxkCDEALxACUKFCmGwtCWZFoJGEGA1jy1OqVFxtHwIlN%20-wE429Ec1pm1CtjJHj5MpNKp3qAA)

Comment: Note that TypeScript considers `SpecialArray` to be a special type of Array called a [`Tuple`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

In this case:

```
type SpecialArray<T extends DataKeys = DataKeys> = [T, Data[T]]
const arr1: SpecialArray = ['FOO', 'wrong'] // no error
```

You omitted the generic parameter, so the default is used. And since the default type `DataKeys` is all keys then the resulting value type is `number | string`.

However, all generic parameters *must* have a type assigned to them, so it doesn't work if you only remove the default:

```
type SpecialArray<T extends DataKeys> = [T, Data[T]]
const arr1: SpecialArray = ['FOO', 'wrong'] // error
// Generic type 'SpecialArray' requires 1 type argument(s).(2314)
```

It does work if you specify the generic parameter:

```
// errors as expected
const arr1: SpecialArray<'FOO'> = ['FOO', 'wrong'] // 2nd argument should be `number`
const arr2: SpecialArray<'BAR'> = ['BAR', 666] // 2nd argument should be `string`
```

But that's not exactly pretty.

Sadly, you just can't infer a generic parameter from a simple assignment in typescript.

The typical workaround for this is to use a function to make the objects for you. Since, as you note functions handle this better.

```
function makeSpecialArray<
  T extends DataKeys
>(key: T, value: Data[T]): SpecialArray<T> {
  return [key, value]
}

// these are type errors, and the objects they create are SpecialArray<SomeKey>
const arr1 = makeSpecialArray('FOO', 'wrong') // 2nd argument should be `number`
const arr2 = makeSpecialArray('BAR', 666) // 2nd argument should be `string`
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKUBiB5PALigDsBXAWwCMIAnLKAIQEEAlYgZ2FoEsSBzDAF8MGUJFgI4AaQggOKKAGs5AewBmkxKPHQAypADGPOABtmtWnBAAeACpQIAD2AQSAEwXxEs+QD5FAG07ABotOGCAXUjRdTISQ2AeVRIoCjgVAwhjMwsrWwdnVw8vKV8OPwAKFRBiUKgANzMyCGJvCLtIgEpiLJzzS2t7AMxsWghgMlpUwJqwptMWmJEMQxSuKDhLAEZFdMyjEwH8yoByfDxTsNOAd1oU-lOuqAB6F6gAJg9N2n5KN2AUA4AAtVGRTO4oDQoAADcjUOgw1brQFbWgfPYZCB9I55axnFisK5QABsZOeb0+3y2fwoAKBoPBkOhMK4vAEMKAA)

Comment: Since `DataKeys` is a finite union, you can represent the desired `SpecialArray` type as a finite union without involving generics.  I would only use a helper function in the case where the type would have to be an infinite union (e.g., a value of the form `[T, T]` for any `T extends string`).

Comment: @jcalz I feel silly I didn't realize that, but you're right! OP, jcalz's answer is better, as usual :) I would probably accept that one over mine.

Answer (score 2):

In a situation like this you really just want `SpecialArray` to be a specific [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the form `["FOO", number] | ["BAR", string]`.  This meets all your needs:

```
type SpecialArray = ["FOO", number] | ["BAR", string]
const arr1: SpecialArray = ['FOO', 'wrong'] // error
const arr2: SpecialArray = ['BAR', 666] // error
const arr3: SpecialArray = ['FOO', 123] // okay
const arr4: SpecialArray = ['BAR', 'right'] // okay
```

So the question here is just "how can I compute `SpecialArray` from `Data`?"

---

There's no reason to keep `SpecialArray<T>` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, but if you do have it generic in `T`, you want to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the type operation across any unions in `T`.  Your current version just produces a single tuple type:

```
type SpecialArray<T extends DataKeys = DataKeys> = [T, Data[T]]
type Test = SpecialArray;
// type Test = [keyof Data, string | number]
```

You can use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to distribute type operations across unions:

```
type SpecialArray<T extends DataKeys = DataKeys> = 
   T extends any ? [T, Data[T]] : never;

type Test = SpecialArray; 
// type Test = ["FOO", number] | ["BAR", string]
```

The `T extends any ? XXX : never` looks like a no-op that produces `XXX`, but it has the desired effect of splitting `DataKeys` into `"FOO"` and `"BAR"`, computing each tuple type separately, and then unioning them back together.

---

But as I said you don't need to have `SpecialArray` be generic; you can compute it from `Data` directly via something called a "distributive object type" (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)), where you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over each key in `DataKeys` where the corresponding property is the tuple type you want, and then immediately [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `DataKeys` to get the union of all properties.  Like this:

```
type SpecialArray = { [K in DataKeys]: [K, Data[K]] }[DataKeys];
// type SpecialArray = ["FOO", number] | ["BAR", string]
```

So that's probably what I'd suggest here; make `SpecialArray` a specific (that is, non-generic) distributive object type.  And if `Data` is ever updated, `SpecialArray` will update automatically:

```
type Data = {
  FOO: number
  BAR: string
  BAZ: boolean
}

// type SpecialArray = ["FOO", number] | ["BAR", string] | ["BAZ", boolean];
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKUBiB5PALigDsBXAWwCMIAnLKAIQEEAlYgZ2FoEsSBzDAF8MoSLARwA0hBAcUUANayA9gDMJiANwZR4aAGVIAYx5wANs1q04IPL34AeACpQIAD2AQSAE3nxEGTkFAOlZDgA+BQBtZwAaTThYgF1kvXFnCC4ARgUjCFMLKxs7Bx0AenKoMWhMnJjlEHVEhK5eASgAH1JKGlo09OgYHjaeKmLbFzdPbz8lVQ1QhUbm0KjUVw8vX3k4EhAoAH4oWITQlOSoYhIIADc6HRqoOuAQke4xiZAtKErq-WeWVeqGiACJ8HhQQlyNQ6JdumCWKwoVBRgIBoMoPlCpZrLYFGgTlIoHxEkEOMliNEpGdJNTUlAhNFQuTkhUqk9sWZcSUYuCCCiYX14SdQUiUWj+ANjCoSFwoHBrNliFyiniDiCAOQQzUJTUAd1osv4msufzoRvoMrlr0VtAATCqTNyvjFNUjdVAAGw+s1VC0qK2y+V2gDMToKLvVbp1CWy9tDfqgKkUtgw1pD1gALBGca6tR69Q4ABbAU2-KoptO6coAKn+4iWqEw2Ah116dAYSM4HwEXeYAC1iFQVCpzBA9sIMLXyhg-pznWreSD+ZDoR3+l1ReLWr2pVvEYOUSOxxOSMkgA)